# JSON.parse() fails with unexpected token using Songkick API

Tags: json, node.js, api

I'm trying to parse a response from the Songkick API with the following in Node:

```
router.post('/', function(req, res) {
  var artist = req.body.artist;
  var id;
  res.render('artist', { title: 'Artist', artist: artist });
  http.request({host: 'api.songkick.com', path: '/api/3.0/search/artists.json?query=' + artist + '&apikey=myAPIKey'}, function(res) {
    res.on("data", function(chunk) {
      id = JSON.parse(chunk).resultsPage.results.artist[0].id;
      console.log(id);
      http.request({host: 'api.songkick.com', path: '/api/3.0/artists/' + id + '/gigography.json?apikey=Z2JWQTvgk4tsCdDn'}, function(res) {
        res.on("data", function(chunk) {
          console.log(JSON.parse(chunk).resultsPage.results);
        });
      }).end();
    });
  }).end();
});
```

However, JSON.parse fails with `SyntaxError: Unexpected token t` (the last character changes depending on the artist requested).

[Here's an example API response.](http://pastebin.com/D8NjWdgw)

How can I fix the syntax error?

Comment: JSON.parse(chunk) <-- Ain't it like that u need to concat the data chunks yourself before u got the total data ? Try to log the chunk and you will see, its probably random length of your response due to networking behaviour.

Comment: You're right... if I log chunk, it gives me a series of buffers. How can I move from those to parseable JSON?

Comment: I've changed your code a bit and posted an answer. It is not tested in action though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

basically the same as the other answer. you need to concat the chunks of data and register for an end event and do the parsing there.
Here's one I tried and it seems to work as expected.

```
var http = require('http');
var artist = 'Beatles'
http.request({host: 'api.songkick.com', path: '/api/3.0/search/artists.json?query=' + artist + '&apikey=Z2JWQTvgk4tsCdDn'}, function(res) {
    var response_data = '';
    var id;
    res.on("data", function(chunk) {
        response_data += chunk;
    });
    res.on('end', function(){
        id = JSON.parse(response_data).resultsPage.results.artist[0].id;
        console.log(id);
        http.request({host: 'api.songkick.com', path: '/api/3.0/artists/' + id + '/gigography.json?apikey=Z2JWQTvgk4tsCdDn'}, function(res) {
            var inner_data = '';
            res.on("data", function(chunk) {
                inner_data += chunk;
            });
            res.on("end", function(){
                console.log(JSON.parse(inner_data).resultsPage.results);
            });
        }).end();
    });
}).end();
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try to concat the string (arriving in chunks) and then use the end event. Like:

```
router.post('/', function(req, res) {
var artist = req.body.artist;
var id;
var data1 = '';
res.render('artist', { title: 'Artist', artist: artist });
http.request({host: 'api.songkick.com', path: '/api/3.0/search/artists.json?query=' +     
artist + '&apikey=myAPIKey'}, function(res) {
res.on("data", function(chunk) {
       data1 += chunk;
    });
    res.on('end', function(){

  id = JSON.parse(data1).resultsPage.results.artist[0].id;
  console.log(id);
  var data2 = '';
  http.request({host: 'api.songkick.com', path: '/api/3.0/artists/' + id + '/gigography.json?apikey=Z2JWQTvgk4tsCdDn'}, function(res) {
    res.on("data", function(chunk) {
       data2 += chunk;
    });
    res.on('end', function(){
      console.log(JSON.parse(data2).resultsPage.results);
    });
  }).end();
});
}).end();
});
```

Basically, it is using data1 and data2 as buffers and calls your function only when all data has arrived.

Comment: Hmm that gives me `JSON.parse(data1).resultsPage.results.artist[0].id;
                                                ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'artist' of undefined`

Comment: Well, I dont know the json of your result string. The API example you provided only lists an 'event' property below results, nothing of the name 'artist'. Use something like http://json.parser.online.fr/ to visualize the json response you get. Aah, and btw: you can only use the [0] if its really an array. Arrays in json are like [value1, value2, value2] (notice the different braces).